# Iterate through a particular values of an enum

Tags: java, spring-boot, for-loop, enums, enumeration

I have the following enum -

```
public enum Colours {
      RED ("RED"),
      BLUE ("BLUE"),
      YELLOW ("YELLOW"),
      GREEN ("GREEN");

private String val;

Colours (String val) {
     this.val = val; }
```

How can I implement this to iterate through the values of enum?

Comment: You can loop over `Colours.values()`, which would return a `Colours[]` of the enum elements. Pedantic, but prefer a class named `Colour` over `Colours` (since the enum constants are singular instances of a `Colour`). Note that `String.valueOf(/* enum const */)` will return the `Enum#name` of the constant, not the `Colours#val` field. Lastly, what are these checks for? You may have an easier time mapping `flag` to any matching `Colours#val` field.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the values() method to get all your enum's values as a list and run through that using a for-each

```
for (Colours colour : Colours.values()) {
    if (flag.equals(colour.val)) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the values of the enum and compare each one with your input. If you find a valid value you can return the enum.

```
    public static Colors getColorEnum(String value) {
        for (Colors c : Colors.values()) {
            if (value.equalsIgnoreCase(c.val)) {
                return c;
            }
        }
        //You can also throw a runtime exception if you want
        throw new RuntimeException("There was a problem with the color enum.");
    }
```

I personally use this approach in many situations. You can also use [ordinal](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/enum_ordinal.htm) but i think it is obsolete.